# if string is empty in discord bot

Tags: c#, bots, discord

I'm trying to check if the input command contains a string given, if not it should return with an example.

The user types `$random` followed by options that will be chosen from randomly.
If there are no options given it should return with an example.

Sadly the `if statement` doesn't do the trick.

Here is my code snippet.

```
 [Command("random")]
    public async Task random([Remainder]string message)
    {

        var embed = new EmbedBuilder();

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
        {
            embed.WithDescription("Example: $random option1|option2|option3");
        }

        string[] options = message.Split(new char[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        Random randNr = new Random();
        string slection = options[randNr.Next(0, options.Length)];


        embed.WithTitle("Choise for " + Context.User.Username);
        embed.WithDescription(slection);
        embed.WithColor(new Color(Color.DarkGreen.RawValue));


        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", false, embed);
    }
```

Comment: What does `message` contain?

Comment: Either return from within `if`, or use an `else` block.

Answer (score 1):

when you detect options is null or empty , donot you need to return ?

```
[Command("random")]
public async Task random([Remainder]string message)
{

    var embed = new EmbedBuilder();

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
    {
        embed.WithDescription("Example: $random option1|option2|option3");
        // miss return proecess? 
    }

    string[] options = message.Split(new char[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    Random randNr = new Random();
    string slection = options[randNr.Next(0, options.Length)];


    embed.WithTitle("Choise for " + Context.User.Username);
    embed.WithDescription(slection);
    embed.WithColor(new Color(Color.DarkGreen.RawValue));


    await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", false, embed);
}
```